# Finishing multithread program in C after M executions?

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, producer-consumer

So, I know you guys love to go into details and I promise to provide more as much as they seem to be really relevant, but for my case what you should bear in mind is the following:

1. I have P threads that are producers
2. I have C threads that are consumers
3. I have a buffer of N elements
4. I want to finish the program after it consumes M elements.

How can I do that?

Below you have my main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    /* Verify the correct number of arguments were passed in */
    if(argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE:./main.out <INT> <INT> <INT>\n");
    }
    int mainSleepTime = atoi(argv[1]); /* Time in seconds for main to sleep */
    int numProd = atoi(argv[2]); /* Number of producer threads */int numCons = atoi(argv[3]); /* Number of consumer threads */
    /* Initialize the app */
    initializeData();
    /* Create the producer threads */
    for(i = 0; i < numProd; i++) {
        /* Create the thread */
        pthread_create(&tid,&attr,producer,NULL);
    }
    /* Create the consumer threads */
    for(i = 0; i < numCons; i++) {
        /* Create the thread */
        pthread_create(&tid,&attr,consumer,NULL);
    }
    /* Sleep for the specified amount of time in milliseconds */
    /* Exit the program */
    sleep(mainSleepTime);
    printf("Exit the program\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Right now the program computes during the sleeping time. But I want to measure the different times it will take to do M executions if I vary N. InitializeData is just a function to work on the buffer. I believe this trick should be solved in the main. Can anybody help me?

Comment: How are you going to make sure there are at least M elements to be processed? Especially, when M > N

Comment: Well, this is also a part of my doubt =P, I am really confused on how to implement this part. I am new into multithread programming, I am still trying to learn it. The point here is that I will vary N from 2 to 32 (powers of 2), I want M to be 1000 and I want to measure how long it will take for each case.

Comment: This is the real problem. You have to decide how you are going to pass the data from producers to consumers. You decision will give you directly the answer when to stop.

Comment: I see, my main issue here is in fact in the main function, I can easily apply some simple logic on either producer or consumer side to send a signal or stop producing/consuming after M runs, but what should I write in the main function to make the threads work until it happens, after I have created then? A friend of mine wrote the following in cpp: `for(auto& t : producers_and_consumers) {
        t.join();
    }`, but I just don't understand what is going on here...

Comment: Make a common point where producers report how many entities created and consumers how many entities are processed. Guard that point with mutex. Stop producers when M entities are created. Monitor that common point from the `main()` and exit when consumers reported about finishing M entities.

Comment: I believe I understood in high-level what you meant, could you elaborate that as an answer (which I can also mark as solved if it is actually the case) so I can better understand how to apply it (which is also a problem for me right now)?

Comment: I find it hard to understand your question. You basically laid out what needs to be done, you need to wait for the required elements to be processed (I assume you don't mean "consumed" as you wrote but actually "processed") and then shut down. Which part of these gives you problems?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following as an example:

```
struct 
{
    int nProducednProduced;
    pthread_mutex_t producerMutex;
    int nConsumed;
    pthread_mutex_t consuerMutex;
} monitor;
```

The `monitor` is a global object visible from all the threads and initalized by `main()` before thread creation.

The producers should increment `monitor.nProduced` and stop/exit when it reaches M.

The consumers increment `monitor.nConsumed` and stop/exit when it reaches M.

`main()` either monitors `monitor.nConsumed` and exit when it reaches M ***or*** simply waits until all the producers and consumers finished.

Comment: I see, in my case I must finish after M. No or case. Once they all finished, eventually a producer will emerge and keep the wheel. Thank you for the help, due to time zone I must leave now, later I return to give a better feedback, but now I understood it a little bit better =)

Comment: end the threads with the statement: `pthread_exit( NULL );`  and have the main() function what one each thread using a loop that employees: `pthread_join()`

Answer (score 0):

Just write a global function accessible by both producer and consumer and guard this function's entry and exit points with mutex in order to safe guard this critical section from multiple simultaneous access. Now inside this function you can use a counters to check how many items are produced by producer and how many items are consumed by consumer. This can happen if you call this function from producer code at a point before producer produces item. Similarly you can call this function after consumer consumes a item.